# Where and how can I download XCOM: Enemy Unknown Patch #2?

Tags: pc, xcom-enemy-unknown

One question: where and how can I download XCOM: Enemy Unknown Patch #2 for PC? (link, please)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Once you'll connect to the internet with the game it will be downloaded automatically. Make sure you are not in offline mode in steam.